# Compare a list with looped txt file

Tags: python

I have a function called `new_safe()` and I made a lst with new safe numbers. Now I need to read the `sae.txt` file with a for loop. Every number that is in `safe.txt` needs to be deleted from the lst I made.

```
def nieuwe_kluis():
  lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
  for lijst in lst:
    print(lijst)
  file = open('kluizen.txt', 'r')
  for line in file:
    if lst == file:
      lst.remove(file)
    print(line)
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You get the lines from the file, but you use file in the comparison and the remove rather than line.
You also don't check if the line (which I assume is one number per line) is a number within the list. Instead you just try to compare the list itself.

Assuming that each line in the file contains one number, you should try something along the lines of

```
  for line in file:
    number = int(line)
    if number in lst:
      lst.remove(number)
    print(line)
```

Comment: thnx for your reply, what you have told me is the opposite of what I want to know. We have to assume that the list contains 12 numbers and the lines in the file dont contain all of them numbers. If the number is in the file, the lst nead to be changed, and printed